# SQL Assertion: MGR_DEPT_ASSERT

Tags: sql

I have the following tables in my DB

```
Employee(Fname, Lname, SSN(PK), Address, Salary, Dno(FK))

Department(Dname, Dnumber(PK), Mgr_ssn(FK))
```

I want to create an assertion that will check that for employee whom work as managers, the department number (Dno) in the EMPLOYEE table matches the department number for the department they manage in the Department table.

I have created the following assertion but I am not sure if it satisfy the requirements.

```
  CREATE ASSERTION MGR_DEPT_ASSERT
CHECK ( EXIST (SELECT  SSN, Dnumber from 
Employee, Department WHERE Dno= Dnumber AND SSN=Mgr_ssn))
```

I'll appreciate your help,

Thanks

Comment: The best way to make sure something works the way you expect is to thoroughly unit test it.

Comment: the DBMS I'm using dose not support assertion, that is why I cannot test it.

Comment: **No** DBMS supports assertions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you make that "no _SQL_ DBMS supports assertions" ?

Comment: @ErwinSmout: user3077030 refers to assertions as defined in the SQL standard. So a non-SQL DBMS can't implement that anyway - at least not the one that user3077030 is referring to

Comment: Ah yes the eternal devastating choice between regarding the semantic/functional equivalent as really being assertions or not based on mere syntactic differences.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The only database values that are going to be stopped by this assertion are empty tables.  (Or more precisely, anything that results in an empty join.)

And BTW, *why* do you want the ASSERTION ?  No products support this [reliably] in practice.  Unless you're willing to ditch SQL, that is.